# How to get highest key and its value from a subdocument in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongo document, the data sub document contains the data for a particular minute for the time stamp. And I want to extract the  key with the maximum value for the data sub document. In this case it would be the key 59.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("565ab6007c7925aae95afd89"), 
    "gatewayId" : NumberInt(12), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 05:00:00", 
    "data" : {
        "2" : {
            "day_chan1" : NumberInt(11), 
            "day_chan2" : NumberInt(11), 
            "day_chan3" : NumberInt(7)
        }, 
         "58" : {
            "day_chan1" : NumberInt(642), 
            "day_chan2" : NumberInt(635), 
            "day_chan3" : NumberInt(427)
        }, 
        "59" : {
            "day_chan1" : NumberInt(653), 
            "day_chan2" : NumberInt(647), 
            "day_chan3" : NumberInt(434)
        }
    }
}
```

I have though of aggregate but couldn't find the appropriate query for this.

Comment: Change your documents structure and you will find the appropriate query

Comment: This is the appropriate structure according to the mongodb blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using map-reduce.

```
db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "collection",
    "query": {"_id" : ObjectId("565ab6007c7925aae95afd89")},
    "map" : function() {
        maxKey = null;
        for(var k in this.data) { 
            if(maxKey == null || maxKey < k){
                maxKey = k
            }
        }
        emit(maxKey, this.data[maxKey]);
    },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) {
        return {key: stuff};
    }, 
    "out": {inline : 1},
})
```

However, I agree with *user3100115*'s comment - you would be better served by changing your data structure to something like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("565ab6007c7925aae95afd89"), 
    "gatewayId" : NumberInt(12), 
    "timestamp" : "2015-09-21 05:00:00", 
    "data" : [
        {
            "key": 2,
            "day_chan1" : NumberInt(11), 
            "day_chan2" : NumberInt(11), 
            "day_chan3" : NumberInt(7)
        }, 
        {
            "key": 58,
            "day_chan1" : NumberInt(642), 
            "day_chan2" : NumberInt(635), 
            "day_chan3" : NumberInt(427)
        }, 
        {
            "key": 59,
            "day_chan1" : NumberInt(653), 
            "day_chan2" : NumberInt(647), 
            "day_chan3" : NumberInt(434)
        }
    ]
}
```

Which makes it possible to use the aggregation-framework:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{
       "_id": ObjectId("565ab6007c7925aae95afd89")
    }},
    {$unwind: "$data"},
    {$sort: {"data.key" : -1}},
    {$limit: 1}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of that but I am a bit apprehensive since I wanted to follow the pattern prescribed in the mongodb blog.